# complexity analysis of RSA algorithm

Tags: algorithm, rsa

The security of RSA hinges upon a simple assumption:

> Given N, e, and y = (x ^e) mod N, it is computationally intractable to
>   determine x.

This assumption is quite plausible. How might Eve try to guess x?

She could experiment with all possible values of x, each time checking whether x^e is equal to  y mod N, but this would take exponential time. Or she could try to factor N to retrieve p and q, and then figure out d by inverting e modulo (p-1)(q-1), but we believe factoring to be hard. Intractability is normally a source of dismay; the insight of RSA lies in using it to advantage.

My question on above text

1. How we got exponential time for calcuation for each value of x in above context?

Comment: It is always easier to factor the modulus instead of brute-forcing a single plaintext to check against a single ciphertext [*citation needed*]. What you're proposing with brute-forcing the plaintext is also not useful, because you would only get a single plaintext without the ability to actually reveal the RSA private exponent.

Comment: Conventionally, factoring complexity (and many other number theory algorithms) is expressed as a function of the **number of digits** in the modulus. If N is an integer then c*ln(N) is the number of digits in N, where c is a constant that is determined  by what radix a "digit" is.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

> ...the time complexity is generally expressed as a function of the
>   **size of the input**

The size of the input of this task is proportional to `b` = the number of bits in `N`. Thus the iteration through all possible values of `x` has time complexity `O(2^b)` that is exponential.

The algorithms that have a polynomial time complexity in terms of **numeric value** of the input are called [pseudo-polynomial algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time). For example, it is well known that [integer factorization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) has no known polynomial algorithm. But we can simply iterate from `2` to `sqrt(N)` and find all prime factors of number `N` in `O(sqrt(N))` time. This algorithm has a polynomial complexity in terms of `N`, but the length of the input of this problem is not `N`, it is `log(N)` approximately. As a result, this iteration is only a pseudo-polynomial solution.

Comment: Thanks for clarfitying. Request to please elaborate. What does k mean here.

Comment: @venkysmarty, sorry, I've made a mistake, fixed that

Comment: Thanks. What does statement " length of the input of this problem is not N it is logN, so it is pseudo polynomial" mean  here

Comment: @venkysmarty, I've rephrased these statements